# iPhone app leaves 20 pixel gap above nav bar when internet hotspot blue bar is visible.

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a strange problem.

My app renders with a 20 pixel gap above its navigation bar when the phone either has an active hotspot connection or if a background app is recording. See Screen shots. The windows root view controller is set to be a navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: In my opinion you are taking a view of size height 460  rather than 480....

Comment: `UIViewController` isn't set to use full screen layout. Something like `[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]`.

Comment: wantsFullScreenLayout is true on the UINavigationController but is false on the nav controllers UIViewController. Should they both be true?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in viewDidLoad of your controller

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```